# Background refusing to show on flex-box

Tags: html, css

So recently I've been trying to get a background image in my small box on my website. But for the life of me I cannot get it to show a background image. Though, it WILL show a color. So I at least know it's formatted at least somewhat right. Here is the box.

[The Culprit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojMU4.png)

If I can get this guy to have a background image opposed to a color I'd be very greatful!

Here is my code

```css
.posts{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-image: url(logo.png);
    background-size: 20%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 900px;
}

.row {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.post-shorts{
    flex-basis: 31%;
    border-radius: 13px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(PlaceHolderImage.png);
    transition-duration: .5s;
}

.post-shorts:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.234);
    flex-basis: 40%;
    background-image: url(PlaceHolderImage2.png);
}

.post-col {
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<section class="posts">
  <h1>POSTS</h1>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="post-shorts">
      <div class="post-col">
        <h3>Shorts</h3>
        <p>Animated using Blender</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Thank you!

I tried switching around the background's position, its alignment, and it's overflow/repeating. Nothing seemed to work for it.

Comment: Have you confirmed in the browser's development tools if the image is being successfully fetched from the server in the first place?

Comment: First time building a page. It looks like it can't reach the image despite being in my local folder. All the other images work for my backgrounds and logos. Strange how this one doesn't seem to want to work though.

Comment: *"It looks like it can't reach the image despite being in my local folder."* - Where/how/why specifically does it look like that?  What specific problem are you observing in your browser's development tools?

Comment: So right now how I have my resources laid out is I have my index and webpages in a folder next to the images. Since they're all in the same folder I can go ahead and access them easily.

I have a white paper background on my webpage that is in this folder and works perfectly. I also have a logo as well on my header.

So when I went to put this placeholder image as my background I assumed it would work the same as the others, as in just copy the relative path and put it in the URL. But on the web developer tools it tells me that it failed to find the file. Even when I copy the full path.

Comment: *"But on the web developer tools it tells me that it failed to find the file."* - What URL is being requested for this file?  What is the exact response from the server and/or the exact error message in the console?  Compare/contrast that with a "working" image that uses the same approach.  What are the differences?

Comment: The url being requested is a local one in the same folder. So all I have to do is copy the file name and it's able to find it. I used this approach with other graphics on the page and it worked fine. But something to note is a commentor below recommended that I try an actual url in the sense of a png on the web. So I copy and pasted that url and it seemed to work! It's just strange to me that a local file, on my desktop, in the same folder as other graphics that do load, refuse to load.

Comment: *"So I copy and pasted that url and it seemed to work!"* - Then the problem is resolved?  *"It's just strange to me that a local file, on my desktop, in the same folder as other graphics that do load, refuse to load."* - The file itself is not actively refusing your request.  Switching between file system paths and URL paths is probably confusing you in some way, as the two are very much not interchangeable.  But without specific debugging information, all anybody can do is guess.

Comment: Yup, I'll chalk it up to some of my own errors and inexperience. Something is wrong with the computer on my end I'm sure, otherwise that link below wouldn't have worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just figured out the solution. Will add it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a real background url when using the `url(PlaceHolderImage2.png);`

example
`url(https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1673306778968-5aab577a7365?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8YmFja2dyb3VuZCUyMGltYWdlfGVufDB8fDB8fHww);`

Comment: Seemed to work! I was trying to use a local file that must be buggy I am presuming. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, found what the issue is. I was using Visual Studio Code and for some reason the files were being accessed with \ instead of /

Really a simple issue. After I switched to that they worked.